# Which model to consider in Geodjango? The initial one or the one generated by ogrinspect?

Tags: django, geodjango

I have made models initially for my application as given in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/
After which i did ogrinspect and it generated a model. The difference between the model initially and the one ogrinspect generated was geometry field.

Initially model has

```
mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()
objects = models.GeoManager()
```

And the one which ogrinspect generated has

```
geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
objects = models.GeoManager()
```

SO which model should i want to consider? whether i should replace the existing model with one which was generated by ogrinspect and do migrate or no need of replacing?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the coordinate system of your input data. If your input data is a shapefile for instance, you can look in its `.prj` file, determine (with that handy [service](http://prj2epsg.org/search)) that the SRID should be XYZ, and then you can pass that value as an `--srid XYZ` option to `python manage.py ogrinspect`, which will then generate the proper `models.MultiPolygonField(srid=XYZ)` geometry object, with the right coordinate system.